# Function scoping issue

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a method called insert_user which is working fine in other parts of the application but for some reason it's undefined in this case and cannot figure out why

```
** (CompileError) test/models/user_repo_test.exs:8: undefined function insert_user/1
    (stdlib) lists.erl:1338: :lists.foreach/2
    (stdlib) erl_eval.erl:670: :erl_eval.do_apply/6
    (elixir) lib/code.ex:376: Code.require_file/2
    (elixir) lib/kernel/parallel_require.ex:59: anonymous fn/2 in Kernel.ParallelRequire.spawn_requires/5
```

This is the code:

```
defmodule Rumbl.UserRepoTest do
  use Rumbl.ModelCase
  alias Rumbl.User

  @valid_attrs %{name: "A User", username: "eva"}

  test "converts unique_constraint on username to error" do
    insert_user(username: "eric")
    attrs = Map.put(@valid_attrs, :username, "eric")
    changeset = User.changeset(%User{}, attrs)

    assert {:error, changeset} = Repo.insert(changeset)
    assert {:username, "has already been taken"} in changeset.errors
  end
end
```

This is the definition at t`est/support/test_helpers.ex`

```
defmodule Rumbl.TestHelpers do

  alias Rumbl.Repo

  def insert_user(attrs \\ %{}) do
    changes = Enum.into(attrs, %{
      name: "Some User",
      username: "user#{Base.encode16(:crypto.strong_rand_bytes(8))}",
      password: "supersecret",
    })

    %Rumbl.User{}
    |> Rumbl.User.registration_changeset(changes)
    |> Repo.insert!()
  end

  def insert_video(user, attrs \\ %{}) do
    user
    |> Ecto.build_assoc(:videos, attrs)
    |> Repo.insert!()
  end
```

Comment: In your test file you could try prepending the module name to the function, so `insert_user(username: "eric")`, would be `TestSupport.insert_user(username: "eric")`, or you could import this function in your tests: `import TestSupport, only: [insert_user: 1]`. Do either of those work for you?

Comment: It complains about TestSupport not being loaded, I try to load it with use Rumbl.TestHelper or import TestSupport. only.... etc and doesnt work neither

Comment: I wasn't aware of what was your fully qualified name of support module - in this case, could you try my suggestions and replace `TestSupport` with `Rumbl.TestHelper`?

Comment: I updated the answer with the full module definition

Comment: I tried what you suggested and it says ** (UndefinedFunctionError) function Rumbl.TestHelper.insert_user/1 is undefined (module Rumbl.TestHelper is not available)

Comment: does your mix.exs has test/support listed in elixirc_paths. For example, I have: 
    def project do
    [
    ...
      elixirc_paths: ["lib", "web", "test/support"]
    ...
    ]
    end 

; usually this is done on per env basis

Comment: I was missing the import inside the Rumbl.ModelCase... omg, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you didn't import `Rumbl.TestHelpers` in the `Rumbl.ModelCase` in `using` macro block, you have to add it explicitly in your test suite to have this functions imported.

It should help, but otherwise - please check that your `TestHelpers` is placed in `test/support` directory. In `mix.exs` you should have a function like this:

```
defp elixirc_paths(:test), do: ["lib", "web", "test/support"]
```

So without placing your file in proper directory, it won't be loaded.

Comment: goddamnit that was it! I am following a book and it didnt say anything about adding the Rumbl.TestHelper into ModelCase import and it was driving me nuts. After adding it it works fine